# MobilePush - Include API request payload attributes in message body

Tags: mobilepush

I'm having trouble getting payload attributes to display in the message body in MobilePush.  I've tried using the CustomKeys and CustomPayload fields in the request, neither worked.  Is the message body not able to access these fields using the standard %%Attribute%% format?  This is very easy on the triggered email side, but the same approach doesn't seem to be working for mobile push.

The business example we're solving for here is the ability to send push notifications such as 'Thanks, we got order XXXXX, please click this link to see your order: XXXX'.  How do I push the dynamic attributes into the message body without requiring that the message be fully constructed within the request? (doing it that way would require a code change to our calling application for simple changes to these push notifications).

Comment: Do you expect these messages to be customized server-side by SFMC and delivered fully rendered to the application or do you expect the application to apply the customizations?

Comment: I expect SFMC to insert the attribute values from the request payload and pass the fully formed message to the application to display as a push notification.  Actually - I just tried this with journey builder using an API entry event and it worked as expected.  I think we'll probably pivot over to Journey builder to handle these push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the MobilePush Demographics to personalize the push messages being sent to your customers.  You can find the MobilePush Demographics in your contact model and it will show you the correct name for each demographic you wish to use.  For instance, I have `%%=firstName%%` set up for my own application and am greeted with, "Hello, Bill, ..."

Comment: Thanks Bill - still not exactly what we want to do.  We want to send order confirmation / ship confirmation / delivery confirmation type messaging.  The order numbers won't really makes sense at the demographic level, rather they are a single use per message and then 'done'.  I've moved my config over to Journey builder and have instead used the API entry point with a Push notification message send.  It does exactly what I need.  Appreciate the help here.