# MobilePush Include Custom Payload attributes in push message

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush

I would like to show the customPayload attributes in my pushmessages.
I tried using %%customattribute%% and some other variants, but no luck so far.

The business case is that I would like to show order and shipping details in the pushmessage. Storing this type of information in the mobilepush demographics would not work.
Also, JourneyBuilder is not an option in this case, unfortunately.

This question is asked previously but was not answered. ([MobilePush - Include API request payload attributes in message body](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325856/mobilepush-include-api-request-payload-attributes-in-message-body))

SF docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSendPush.htm

Comment: why don't you simply override the message with the dynamic test you want to send?

Comment: Hi @EazyE Thank you for your comment. I'm familiar with the override function, but that's not our best option in this case. I would like to know if it's possible (and how) to use the custom payload as dynamic content.

Comment: Cant you use a API triggered journey and use the DE fields in the push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible,

You have a few options

1. Create Mobile Demographics to store these values to be used in the message.
2. Use a journey to send these and use the API entry event
3. Hold these values in another DE and use ampscript lookup
4. Provide the override message in the PUSH api to be the dynamic message you want to send

Comment: Thanks. Too bad you can't use the custom payload for this. I wonder what the use of this option is then. Not very well documented (or I'm unable to find the correct documentation lol).

Comment: The custom payload is not accessible by the message through ampscript or anything of the such.  Usually the custom payload is used to send down additional information that gets appended to the notification.  Your application would then use this payload for anything it needed.  The suggestions above are all great examples of how to get your details into the notification message.